# Counting eloquent relations from pivot table in L4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, relational-database, eloquent, eager-loading

I have the following tables:

**users**

```
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username', 30);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**organisations**

```
    Schema::create('organisations', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique('name');
        $table->integer('owner_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and this is my **organisation_user** pivot table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('organisation_user', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('organisation_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('organisation_id')->references('id')->on('organisations')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('staff_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('staff_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

My model's rules are:

- An organisation belongs to one user (owner) - not always, i.e. `nullable` owner_id
- An organisation may have many users under it (staffs)

Therefore, my `Organisation` eloquent model looks like this:

```
class Organisation extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'owner_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function staffs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User', 'staff_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

This is how I load the model in my controller and pass it to the view:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('organisations.index')
        ->with('organisations', Organisation::with('owner', 'staffs')->get());
}
```

On my view, I display the data like this:

```
@foreach($organisations as $organisation)
    <div>
        Name : {{  $organisation->name }}
        <br>
        Owner: {{ $organisation->owner->email }}
        <br>
        Staffs: {{ $organisation->staffs->count() }}
    </div>
@endofreach
```

When the above executes, I get the following error:

## SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.staff_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`staff_id` in (1))

Any idea why I might be doing wrong here? How do you link the relationship with eager loading correctly?

Do I need a separate model for the pivot table for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like `staffs` is actually a [many-to-many relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many). That means you need `belongsToMany()`

```
public function staffs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'organisation_user', 'organisation_id', 'staff_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am not getting any error anymore, however the result is now `0`. I have data in the pivot table. Any ideas?

Comment: The query it's generating is: `SELECT `organisations`.*, `organisation_user`.`staff_id` as `pivot_staff_id`, `organisation_user`.`organisation_id` as `pivot_organisation_id` FROM `organisations` inner join `organisation_user` on `organisations`.`id` = `organisation_user`.`organisation_id` WHERE `organisation_user`.`staff_id` in ('1')` which doesn't look right.

Comment: Looks like the foreign keys are switched around. Do you have them like in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Many to many relationships use the `belongsToMany()` method, not the `hasMany()` method.

Update your code:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function staffs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Organisation', 'organisation_user', 'staff_id','organisation_id');
    }
}
```

Also in the view, try this
`Staffs: {{ $organisation->staffs()->count() }}`

Note the only change is the added `()` to staff, I can't test this code myself but from what I remember the `->staffs` method would return an `Eloquent\Collection` of all the related models (`Users`) and with the `()` would return the `hasMany()` object you defined in the relation method in the model which has other functionality compared to the `Eloquent\Collection`

Double check the Eloquent documentation on many to many relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am not getting any error anymore, however the result is now `0`. I have data in the pivot table. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll update the answer, watch this space
Scratch that, how are you loading the relations when querying?

Comment: All my code is posted in the question. I assumed by defining the relationship, Eloquent made the right queries? Have I missed a step?

Comment: Updated the answer again